# I can't find the .exe file that qt-creator is supposed to be making

Tags: c++, qt-creator

This is my first time using Qt-creator and I just got done coding my program and I want to put it on a USB and use it on a different computer but when I go to where my project is located at C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Calculator 
I don't see any .exe files the only files i see are a 
1  .pro file,
2. another .pro file,
3 .cpp file,
4 .cpp file,
5 .h file,
6 .ui file,.
I have built the project in Qt-creator and everything runs fine and my program works without any errors  when i run it inside of Qt-creator. I do not have a debug or release folder like some people say I should.
so my question is, where can I find/create the .exe file for my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have done a shadow build, that means you build isn't located at your source.

You can find out where your build is located when you open the Projects Mode in creator. On the top should be marked your project. Then select the Build & Run tab. Select your Kit and switch to the build settings. Locate the Build directory in the opened page.

That should be the location where your binaries are build.